# Change the list of dropdown according to the selection of other dropdown

Tags: php

I have two dropdowns .i want second dropdown list shoul changed according to the value selected in first dropdown.

this is my first dropdown

```
Category :<select name="Category" id="a1_txtBox5" required="required">
                       <option value="select">select..</option>
                       <?php while($selectcategoryarray=mysql_fetch_array($selectcategory)) {
                       ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $selectcategoryarray[1];?>"><?php echo $selectcategoryarray[1];?></option>
                        <?php
                        }
                        ?>
                    </select>
```

And here is my second dropdown:

```
<label style="margin-left:24px;">Subcategory :</label><select style="margin-right:35px;" name="subcategory" id="a1_txtBox3" required="required">
                        <option value="select"> select..</option>
                        <?php while($selectsubcategoryarray=mysql_fetch_array($selectsubcategory)) {
                       ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo  $selectsubcategoryarray[2];?>"><?php echo $selectsubcategoryarray[2];?></option>
                        <?php
                        }
                        ?>
                    </select>
```

Please help.

Comment: you need to ajax and php for do this try simple way http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18207689/2nd-dropdown-list-based-on-the-value-of-first-drop-down-list

Answer (score 0):

Exactly you need to handle the `Change Event` for your first `Select` element and in the body of the event you need to send request to server for getting data of second Select element.
I recommend to use an `ajax` process to doing this.
And o this you should use `jQuery` for handling events and have ajax.